# Ruby on Rails - Prompting user for password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, prompt

I'm trying to add some basic file-download functionality to my Rails application and have the `password_hash` and `password_salt` fields for my file model. I also have a function in which a download link to the file is generated, however I'm not totally sure (as I'm sort of reasonably new to Ruby and Rails) how I'd go about actually prompting the user for a password and checking this before proceeding with the file download.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should target you link to a controller and send the file like this:

```
before_filter :login_required
def download
  send_file '/home/railsway/downloads/huge.zip', :type=>"application/zip" 
end
```

this way you can check the password in you before filter using HTTP Basic Auth for example.

more info: http://www.therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right

Comment: I double check that post every time I do downloads.

Comment: I thought about using HTTP basic authentication - but it would look really unproffesional to have a username field that must just be left empty. (I'm correct in saying that HTTP basic auth needs a user and password field right?)

Comment: You're right, It's up to you to use any classic session-based authentication using some Rails plugin, as the download is driven from a controller, you can apply the same authentication as web pages. check: http://railscasts.com/episodes/21-super-simple-authentication

Comment: I've seen this screencast before, however it requires another page for the textbox. I was really hoping for a solution in which the password box could popup.

Comment: mm, maybe you can create a javascript popup when cliking on the link, which will add the password to the request url (hashed of course). But that's not very pretty i think.

Comment: Do you know how I could accomplish this Javascript solution?

Comment: just override the `onClick` using you js framework and use `prompt` to ask the password to the user. then append the sting to your query like `link.set('href', link.get('href') + "&password=" + password)` and let the event finish. of course you may want to add some security to this, but that's up to you ^^

Comment: I think if you don't know how to do it you should stick with the Basic Auth approach, because i don't really have the time to write the code for you, and it will need some more improvement to be secure.